# Codeigniter Email did not Working in Server fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

Please help me in codeigniter Email,
I had many tries but it did not work,
Its working On localhost but did not work on server.

ERROR:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2069
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/b4ger7ik8el2/public_html/account/application/controllers/Welcome.php
>   Line: 105 Function: send
>
> File: /home/b4ger7ik8el2/public_html/account/index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

```
$config = array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                        'smtp_port' => 465,
                        'smtp_user' => 'Email', // change it to yours
                        'smtp_pass' => 'Pasword', // change it to yours
                        'mailtype' => 'html',
                        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                        'wordwrap' => TRUE
                    );

                    $message =  "
                                <html>
                                <head>
                                    <title>Verification Code</title>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                    <h2>Thank you for Registering.</h2>
                                    <p>Dear:".$this->input->POST('firstname')."</p>
                                    <p>Email: ".$this->input->POST('user_email')."</p>
                                    <p>Please click the link below to activate your account.</p>
                                    <h4><a href='".base_url()."welcome/activate/".$email=$this->input->POST('user_email')."/'>Activate My Account</a></h4>
                                </body>
                                </html>
                                ";

                    $this->load->library('email', $config);
                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                    $this->email->from($config['smtp_user']);
                    $this->email->to($this->input->POST('user_email'));
                    $this->email->subject('Signup Verification Email');
                    $this->email->message($message);

                    //sending email
                    if($this->email->send()){
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('Success','Your Account Has Been Created Please Check your email and verify your account..!');
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->email->print_debugger());

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the SSL part from your SMTP string in the config array,

```
config = array(
               'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'Email', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'Pasword', // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
                    );
```

Comment: Try to change the port to 587 and check.

Comment: Did you try print_debugger() ?

Comment: The following SMTP error was encountered: 111 Connection refused
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
config = array(
               'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'Email', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'Pasword', // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
                    );
```

to

```
config = array(
               'protocol' => 'mail',
                'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'Email', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'Pasword', // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
                    );
```

Now it will surely work for you. As it worked for me.